# Java modular packaging for specific customers / builds

Tags: java, ant, osgi, packaging, modular

I'm working with an ERP project. The problem is that we need to modularise the project on specific customer need or specific build basis. 
for example    I have  Java package A , B , C , D 
for customer 1 , I want all of the packages, 
for customer 2 , I want  A B C  included in the build,
for customer 3 , I want  A C D  included in the build  and so on.

This project is Jersey based restful java API. 
I've considered  OSGI, Jigsaw. They are probably not what I need. 
I know I can solve my problem by using ANT based build system, to build with specific java packaging,  But I want to know if there are any elegant solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you building a jar/war?